# Cannot install anything on EC2?

Tags: 14.04, server, amazon-ec2, aws

When I try to install anything on EC2 it gives me bunch of errors saying failed to fetch or unable to fetch.
Here is the error stack:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-88:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  binutils build-essential cpp cpp-4.8 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.8 gcc
  gcc-4.8 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
  libcloog-isl4 libdpkg-perl libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgmp10 libgomp1 libisl10 libitm1 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libquadmath0
  libstdc++-4.8-dev libtsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
  python-chardet-whl python-colorama python-colorama-whl python-distlib
  python-distlib-whl python-html5lib python-html5lib-whl python-pip-whl
  python-requests-whl python-setuptools python-setuptools-whl python-six-whl
  python-urllib3-whl python-wheel python3-pkg-resources
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-4.8-locales debian-keyring g++-multilib
  g++-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc libstdc++6-4.8-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf
  automake1.9 libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-4.8-multilib libgcc1-dbg
  libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg
  libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc libstdc++-4.8-doc make-doc python-genshi
  python-lxml python3-setuptools
Recommended packages:
  python-dev-all
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils build-essential cpp cpp-4.8 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.8 gcc
  gcc-4.8 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
  libcloog-isl4 libdpkg-perl libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgmp10 libgomp1 libisl10 libitm1 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libquadmath0
  libstdc++-4.8-dev libtsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
  python-chardet-whl python-colorama python-colorama-whl python-distlib
  python-distlib-whl python-html5lib python-html5lib-whl python-pip
  python-pip-whl python-requests-whl python-setuptools python-setuptools-whl
  python-six-whl python-urllib3-whl python-wheel python3-pkg-resources
0 upgraded, 50 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 979 kB/41.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 119 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.13.0-92.139
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.176.237.167 80]
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe python-pip-whl all 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.176.237.167 80]
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe python-pip all 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.176.237.167 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.13.0-92.139
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-92.139_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip-whl_1.5.4-1ubuntu3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 54.176.237.167 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip_1.5.4-1ubuntu3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 54.176.237.167 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the following commands first to get everything up to date and running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

These commands will re-initialize the package cache and repository information, as well as upgrade your system to the newest possible version, which will likely deliver a good number of security updates.

Finally, Linux provides this answer to you in the output you posted:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Typically, `apt` is rather user-friendly and will provide helpful tips like shown above to users if/when something goes wrong.